# How to know JAVA_HOME value?

Tags: ubuntu, java-home

How can I know the value of JAVA_HOME variable on Ubuntu Server?

I tried with `echo $JAVA_HOME` but I read a white line.

Answer (score 1):

It's `echo $JAVA_HOME` on a Linux command line.

Comment: When you install Java from an official vendor package, JAVA_HOME should be set for all shell sessions, however, if it's not, you set it manually. See http://www.mshsoftware.com/site/kb/set-java-home-on-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

You might have checked the value immediately after setting it in /etc/environment file.

Solution: Try manually refreshing the file by typing below in the command prompt.

Note: observe the "." before the path "/etc/environment".

`. /etc/environment`

Alternate solution is try [STEP 8](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux#img_bc7ac69f78) shown here.

Answer (score 0):

You can just type:

```
$JAVA_HOME
```

If that doesn't give you anything maybe the variable isn't set up yet, you can try typing:

```
JAVA_HOME=/your_java_home
```

and then typing

```
$JAVA_HOME 'or' echo $JAVA_HOME
```

to see if it works.